# A die is thrown 100 times. What is the variance of the number of even numbers?

Tags: probability, variance

> A die is thrown 100 times. Getting an even number is considered a success. What is the variance of the number of successes?

Comment: Calculate the probabilities of no of even numbers outcomes $N$ from 0 to 100. Then use the formula $$\sigma ^2 = \text{E}(N^2) - (\text{E}(N))^2$$

Comment: By a die, do you mean a six sided die?

Comment: Yes, Benji Altman

Answer (score 3):

p(getting even number) $= \frac 36 = \frac 12$

q(not even number $= \frac 36 = \frac 12$

Variance $= npq$

$= 100 \times \frac 12 \times \frac 12$

$= 25$

Comment: Sorry sir I am unaware of this result. If we use the standard formula will we get the same result?

Comment: Yes if you use standard formula you get same result.

Answer (score 2):

What you are considering is actually a binomial distribution, like exactly in the case of a fair coin. You have a $p=50\% $ probability of getting an even number at each throw. 
The probability distribution of having $k$ successes out of $n$ tries is:
$$f(k;n,p)=\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

The expected number of successes over $n=100$ tries is:
$$E[X]=\sum_{k=0}^n k\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k} =np=100\cdot0.5=50$$
The proof is available on every probability textbook.

The variance is:
$$\sigma^2=E[X^2]-E[X]^2=np(1-p)=25$$

The article on wikipedia is well done. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution